# memory leak with malloc / free with arc

Tags: objective-c, macos, malloc, automatic-ref-counting

I work on image processing app for Mac OSX and have problem with huge memory leaks (I'm using ARC). On main window I've an slider which modyfies values of pixels and updates an image. But when I'm changing slider value my app allocates more and more memory (Few minutes of "sliding" allocates even up to 10 GB of memory!).

App operates on quite big images (30-40mb) in grayscale. I've created 3 C Arrays with my pixels and operate on them but I call `free` but it seems they are not freed.

Changing value of slider fires that method:

```
-(void)changeCurrentMinOrMax
{
    imageProcessQueue = dispatch_queue_create("rwt.tz", NULL);
    dispatch_async(imageProcessQueue, ^{
        // Change display range
        [self setDisplayRangeWithMin:_currentMin andMax:_currentMax];
        // Pack pixels into filtered raw image data
        [self packPixelsIntoFilteredImageData];
        // Create filtered image data
        [self createImage:_rawFilteredImageData];
    });
}
```

and here are implementation of called methods:

```
- (void)setDisplayRangeWithMin:(int)min andMax:(int)max
{
    // Calculate number of gray levels
    NSUInteger numberOfGrayLevels = (NSUInteger)pow(2, _bitsPerPixel);
    // Calculate display range
    int range = max - min;
    // Set treshold
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < numberOFPixels; i++) {
        if (originalPixels[i] < min) {
            pixels[i] = min;
        } else if (originalPixels[i] > max) {
            pixels[i] = max;
        } else {
            pixels[i] = originalPixels[i];
        }
        // map it again into 0-65535 values of gray
        pixels[i] = (UInt16)((numberOfGrayLevels - ZERO_INDEX) * (float)((pixels[i] - min) / (float)range));
    }
}

- (void)packPixelsIntoFilteredImageData
{
    UInt8 *revertedImageDataArray = malloc(sizeOfBitmap);
    unsigned long j = 0;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < sizeOfBitmap; i += 2) {
        revertedImageDataArray[i] = (UInt8)((pixels[j] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        revertedImageDataArray[i+1] = (UInt8)(pixels[j] & 0x00FF);
        j++;
    }

    // pack an array into NSData again
    _rawFilteredImageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:revertedImageDataArray
                                           length:sizeOfBitmap];
    free(revertedImageDataArray);
    revertedImageDataArray = NULL;
}

- (NSImage *)createImage:(NSData *)imgData
{
    _bitsPerComponent = [imgData length] / (_width * _height) * BYTE_SIZE;
    _bitsPerPixel = _bitsPerComponent;
    _bytesPerRow = _width * _bitsPerPixel / BYTE_SIZE;

    CGDataProviderRef provider =
    CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(imgData));
    // which colorspace is better?
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2);
    //CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate((size_t)_width,
                                        (size_t)_height,
                                        _bitsPerComponent,
                                        _bitsPerPixel,
                                        _bytesPerRow,
                                        colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    NSSize size = NSMakeSize((CGFloat) _width, (CGFloat)_height);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
        _image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef
                                             size:size];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    });
    return _image;
}
```

I free my C arrays in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    // Free memory allocated for C arrays
    if (pixels) {
        free(pixels);
        pixels = NULL;
    }
    if (originalPixels){
        free(originalPixels);
        originalPixels = NULL;
    }
    if (imageDataArray8) {
        free(imageDataArray8);
        imageDataArray8 = NULL;
    }
    // Remove observers
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentMax"];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentMin"];
}
```

If I use other C arrays in other places I free them in the same method. It looks like memory is not freed (even when I close current image and open new one) and dealloc is fired. Do you have any idea what is going on? I tear my hair out because of that!

Comment: Great! That was the reason of memory leak! Thank you so much! You can post it as answer and I'll accept it. Just corious, why CFRelease doesn't do the proper work?

Comment: about createImage - You have right so I will call whole `createImage` method in main queue and delete dispatch_async from `createImage`

Comment: Use the static analyzer. It will show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for ypur explanation about this "bridging thing" ;)

Comment: About createImage - I don't use returned image in changeCurrentMinOrMax but in other placec I do... so that's the why I decided to return NSImage for that method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line of code that says:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(imgData));
```

According to the [Managing Toll-Free Bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1) section of the *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes* tells us, though, that:

> `__bridge_retained` or `CFBridgingRetain` casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also transfers ownership to you.
>   You are responsible for calling `CFRelease` or a related function to relinquish ownership of the object.

The `CFBridgingRetain` is simply unneeded here. And you're leaking because you're never releasing the `CFDataRef` you passed to `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData` (you release the provider, but not the `CFDataRef`). You might as well let ARC retain ownership and clean up for you. That's easier than adding the code to (a) keep track of the `CFDataRef` that you transferred ownership to with `CFBridgingRetain` and then (b) manually `CFRelease` the `CFDataRef`. You can just change that line as follows, to not transfer ownership at all, and ARC will take care of the rest (for the `NSData`, that is):

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)imgData);
```

---

Unrelated, but `createImage` is returning `_image`, which is getting set asynchronously, and thus `_image` will not be set by the time you hit that `return` line. You could fix this so it would return the appropriate value, but it turns out that you don't use the return value from `createImage`, so it might be easier to change the return type to `void`. But the current code is just a little confusing, suggesting you're returning something when you're really not.